# Crear copia de tabla

Tags: sql, postgresql

Saludos. Tengo una tabla (datos_basicos), al generar un "proyecto nuevo", cada proyecto hereda datos_basicos. Pero cuando el usuario desee editar estos, lo ideal es que estas modificaciones sean en una tabla "datos_basicos_editables", es decir donde se pueden realizar cambios sin dañar la tabla de datos_basicos.

Maneras de manejar el problema:

- Crear una copia de datos_basicos a datos_basicos_editables y en esta realizar x opeacion
- Una mejor idea o practica?

Con este query puedo crear una tabla a partir de otra, pero existe algo como un INSERT?

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Cuando el query se hace con las declaraciones de arriba, no crea un primary key y aparte de esto, yo necesitaria agregar otras columnas y datos a la tabla para crear la relacion fk_proyecto id 1 a estos datos copiados

**PROCESO**

Se llena formulario y estos van a tabla "proyecto",cada proyecto debe tener datos_basicos. Seria una mala practica usar los datos_basicos para hacer modificaciones, por tanto habria que crear una tabla nueva y que esta este relacionado a cada proyecto y de esta manera hacer modificaciones

Comment: Entonces, ¿cual es tu pregunta en realidad? ¿Y cual es el problema con usar el `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...`?

Comment: hola @sstan acabo de profundizar la pregunta. Quizas una mejor practica para poder relacionar el proyecto creado a esta "copia"

Comment: Para sugerir una mejor practica, tenemos que entender bien el uso de tus tablas y datos. Pero por ahora, la descripción en tu pregunta es muy poca de lo que son los proyectos, los datos básicos, como estos se relacionan y como se usan. Si tu pregunta fuera simplemente cómo se hace X en PostgreSQL, no tendría mayor importancia. Pero en vista de tu pregunta un poco más abierta, creo que debes explicar el contexto con mucha más claridad tomando en cuenta que no sabemos nada en cuenta a tus tablas y su significado y objetivo.

Comment: hola @sstan ya lo acabo de colocar, gracias por la acotacion

Comment: por otro lado, siendo especifico, como haria para copiar los datos de una tabla y llevarlos a otra tabla ya creada? @sstan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Con este query puedo crear una tabla a partir de otra, pero existe algo como un INSERT?
>
> por otro lado, siendo especifico, como haria para copiar los datos de una tabla y llevarlos a otra tabla ya creada?

Me voy a limitar a contestar esta porción de tu pregunta más específica.  Para esto puedes usar la sintaxis `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`:

```
INSERT INTO tabla2 (col1, col2, ..., colN)
SELECT col1, col2, ..., colN
  FROM tabla1
```

Comment: Correcto, Gracias @sstan